# What is the difference between float(44*2.2) and (float)(44*2.2) in PYTHON 3?

Tags: python

If you just type `float(44*2.2)` on the interpreter and `(float)(44*2.2)` they return the same result. Is one explicitly casting the result, and one using it as a function? And what is the use of each case and any pro's/con's for each case? This is Python 3, I'm sure it'll work with Python 2 as well.

Comment: The brackets around `float` don't change anything - `(float)` evaluates as `float`, so both expressions do exactly the same thing.

Comment: type both `float` and `(float)` at the interpreter

Comment: No. Python does not have "casting". Those calls are syntactically *completely identical*.

Comment: @PaulH just tried it and I realise they are the same, thank you! I thought it could be similar to C++ where there is explicitly casting

Comment: @DanielRoseman, Thank you for the clarification, understand it now!

Comment: @ali_m Appreciate it! Was going from C++ to python and thought one was explict casting and other was a function call

Comment: @DanielRoseman, so does python only do implicit casting? Or are there function calls that do this. I know in C++ you can explicitly cast, in C# you can call a function to convert to something.

Comment: In Python there's no way to interpret an object as another object, so the difference between casting and conversion is moot. C++ lets you cast to something completely unrelated.

Comment: P.S. The syntax mistake would have been blindingly clear if you had simply tried `(float)44`.

Comment: @MarkRansom, ahh great example! Thank you for showing me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both usages invoke the built-in function `float`.  In python, functions are just values, so `(float)` is the same function reference as `float`.

There is no casting involved.  I would prefer the first usage, because it's more clear.

Comment: (more clear, I agree, but neither are necessary, at least in the example's case)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I also thank you for suggesting the clearer version.